# How to change the json request format when input is captured via a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have the following form.

```
const MyForm = ({
  myFormRef,
}) => (
  <form id="myForm" ref={myFormRef} method="POST">
    <input name="request_token" type="hidden" />
    <input name="id" type="hidden" />
    <input name="versionId" type="hidden" />
    <input name="additionalId" type="hidden" />
  </form>
);

export default MyForm;
```

We are using useRef hook to reference this form and calling it within another Component as follows.

```
const myFormRef = useRef();

<MyForm
    myFormRef={myFormRef}
/>
```

The `postData` function at the end is in a js file.

Question is on this `postData` function.

This is triggered when a form is submitted via a button click.

It is all working fine where I am capturing correct details and able to submit the form.

**The issue:**

It is the format of how I am sending the data over which is the issue.

I am sending over details in following format in this form.

```
{
    token,
    id,
    versionId,
    additionalId
}
```

Instead I want to send it as:

```
{
    token,
    overallData: {
        id,
        versionId,
        additionalId
    }
}
```

How can I modify the request format to wrap inside overallData for the 3 fields (token is still outside) before submitting?

```
export const postData = (
  myFormRef,
  token,
  myLink,
  id,
  versionId,
  additionalId
) => {
  const fields = {
    request_token: token,
    id,
    versionId,
    additionalId,
  };

  // checking if data exists for a key (example id or token) and remove if no value against the key. 
  [...myFormRef.current.children].forEach((child) => {
    child.value = fields[child.name];
    if (!child.value) {
      myFormRef.current.removeChild(child);
    }
  });

  // then submit
  myFormRef.current.action = myLink;
  myFormRef.current.submit();
};
```

Note: I have to stick with this style to use the form and useRef() due to other dependencies.

Thus looking for a way to possibly modify postData. Else advise other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<form id="myForm" ref={myFormRef} method="POST">
    <input name="request_token" type="hidden" />
    <input name="overallData.id" type="hidden" />
    <input name="overallData.versionId" type="hidden" />
    <input name="overallData.additionalId" type="hidden" />
  </form>
```